# mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback not working Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I am developing an app that access to a web page with WKWebView in Swift. This web starts playing a sound automatically. I want not allow to play the sound automatically. I would like to use something like `mediaPlayBackRequieresUserAction = true` but it doesn't works with WKWebView.

I am trying with something like

```
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypeAll
```

but it is not working, Xcode is showing me:

> Cannot assign value of type '[WKAudiovisualMediaTypes].Type' to type
>   'WKAudiovisualMediaTypes'

The elements that are causing the audio sounds automatically are:

```
<audio src="audio/alarm.mp3" preload="auto" loop="true" class="alarm mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
<audio src="audio/alarm2.mp3" preload="auto" loop="true" class="urgent alarm2 mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

This is my WKWebView code:

```
    import UIKit
import WebKit

class WidgetViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

var webView : WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = URL(string: "https://danfg95glucose.azurewebsites.net/")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false
    webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

    webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect( x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 500 ), configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.load(request)
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
}
    }
```

Sorry for my mistakes, I am new and I am learning programming. Thank you so much for every responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to set mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback once. This should work.

```
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .all
```

You could limit it to just audio with this instead

```
webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = .audio
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am using only one but I have the same problem: `Cannot assign value of type '[WKAudiovisualMediaTypes].Type' to type 'WKAudiovisualMediaTypes'` Do you know what can I do?

Comment: On audio.play() I still get Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission. Even after I have interacted a lot. Also wouldn't setting this to all definitely require user action when I don't want anything to require user action?

Answer (score 1):

so frustrating.
I found that changing mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback at runtime is totally ignored.
the webView configuration still has .none as it's value ☹️

so in the viewDidLoad() of my ViewController I did this

```
private func workaroundAppleUserActionForPlaybackBug() -> WKWebView
{
    // you can set the value in the configuration, but it doesn't actually change!
    // even setting these values in IB doesn't work, it's always ZERO (meaning auto playback)
    //
    let frame = self.webView.frame
    let configuration = self.webView.configuration
    configuration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = WKAudiovisualMediaTypes.all
    
    return WKWebView(frame: frame, configuration: configuration)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.webView = workaroundAppleUserActionForPlaybackBug()
}
```

Comment: I found that I needed to do this as well, thanks for sharing this tip.